# Infer type from an array, dynamically

Tags: arrays, typescript, enums

Hi typescript aficionados,

I'm wondering what solution do you have to infer type from an array ie :

```
const ENVS = ["DEV", "STAGGING", "PROD"];

ENVS.map(ENV => xxxx) // ENV is type as string but I would like it to be "DEV" | "STAGING" | "PROD"
```

So far without using an `enum` or doing `type ENV = "DEV" | "STAGING" | "PROD";`, I want to generate  my type from an array dynamically

I manage to do something like this

```
type ElementType<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer ElementType> ? ElementType : never;

const ENVS = ["DEV", "STAGGING", "PROD"];

ENVS.map((ENV: ElementType<ENVS>) => xxxx) // it works
```

Do you guys have any solution on how to do this ? (every possible solution is appreciated)

Comment: `const ENVS = ["DEV", "STAGGING", "PROD"] as const;`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Perfect, I knew there was an easier solution